# How do I wait for room in the BLE transmit packet queue using NimBLE stack?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I'm using an ESP32-S3 with NimBLE BLE stack as peripheral, and sometimes need to send/notify a mix of two types of data through the same connection. The first byte in each BLE notification denotes which types, we can call them application-bulk and application-control. I've already adjusted PHY coding, MTU, and connection interval timing.

When the queue is full and ble_gatts_notify_custom() is called, it returns BLE_HS_ENOMEM to indicate that the packet was not submitted to the queue.

In my application, sometimes the queue is usually full as large numbers of application-bulk packets will be submitted. It's ok if many drop, as long as a few make it through.

For the application-control packets however, I'd like to the thread submitting them to be able to wait a specified amount of time or connection-events for space in the queue to become available. I've tried polling in a loop using vTaskSuspend() between tries, but this tends to let the thread generating application-bulk packets fill the queue before the application-control packets can be submitted. Is there any NimBLE stack native method for doing so?